# List of drivers for Samsung NP300E5Z-S08IN

Tags: 12.04, drivers, samsung

I am looking for a list of drivers for my samsung model mentioned in the title. For specs please visit the [website](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-np300e5z-s08in-2-gen-ci5-4gb-750gb-1gb-graphics-dos/p/itmd8dhnybfbngtu?pid=COMD8DHN7KUCHY33&ref=b1b65058-550f-49c8-9bd6-e562b46963b9). The laptop came with a version of free-dos installed. I overwrote that one with windows 7 entirely. The laptop also had shipped with it a software cd which had some driver software.

Below are the list of software; I want to know the list of equivalent software I can get for ubuntu from the repo. Would want the list for Ubuntu 12.04

```
Chipset driver
Intel ME Interface Driver
Intel Rapid Storate Technology
Graphics Driver
NVidia graphics driver
sound driver
Lan driver
wireless lan driver
bluetooth driver
touchpad driver
```

Ps: don't forget to check the website for the specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has almost all generic drivers. So everything should work out of box.

However, you can open dash, search for `additional drivers`. This will install nvidia driver.

The spec doesn't specify wireless card. You may need to install that driver.

Best way is to create a cd or live usb and run ubuntu in live mode. So that you can see whether everything works fine or not. If anything doesn't work. Post a question here.